# How to make an android app to access the GPIO's of BeagleBone Black?

Tags: android, beagleboneblack

I want to make an android app to directly access the GPIO's of beaglebone black. I am new to android programming and couldn't find anything so far. Pls Help.

Answer (score 1):

The most work should be done on the beaglebone side. You need to write an [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) - and I would recommend a RESTful one (google it) - to expose whatever GPIO functionality you want. Then you can consume this API from your android device - which is the easy part.

You should look for instructions on how to write such an API. Another term that is closely related to these API's is the IoT (Internet of Things).  An example of such an API  (IoT framework( for Raspberry pi is [webiopi](https://code.google.com/p/webiopi/). You can have a look at [this guide](https://thefloppydisk.wordpress.com/2013/05/08/how-to-build-a-restful-web-api-on-a-raspberry-pi-in-javascript/) on how to build restful api on pi.

I am afraid that there is not so much available documentation for Beaglebone but hopefully you got the picture on what you should look for or implement.